# Спарсить курс BTC/USD

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте!

Помогите спарсить курс BTC/USD с страници `http://markets.blockchain.info/markets/mtgox/USD`

Делаю так:

```
$uri = 'http://markets.blockchain.info/markets/mtgox/USD';
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('#<span id="last_price">([^"]+)</span>#U',$html,$list);
echo $list[1];
```

Но не выходит. Как правильнее записать `preg_match` ?

Comment: спарсить ту цифру которая самая большая

Answer (score 5):

У них есть [API](https://blockchain.info/api)

т.е. юзаем http://blockchain.info/ticker

```
<?php
$uri = 'http://blockchain.info/ticker';
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $ticker = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),1);
echo $ticker['USD']['last']."\n";
```

---

или еще проще:

```
<?php 
$uri = 'http://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=1000'; //сколько btc за $1000 
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo 1000/(float)curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: спасибо вам )

Comment: Ай-яй-яй! Что будет в знаменателе, если **curl_exec** вернет **false**?

Comment: обработчик ошибок я думаю должен писать сам ТС.